# Unable to CAST as TEXT after upgrad to 2.1.212 & 2.1.214

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

After upgrading from 1.4.200 (provided by spring) to H2 2.1.212 and then 2.1.214, I started seeing this error message when attempting to cast as text:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Precision ("2147483647") must be between "1" and "1000000000" inclusive; SQL statement:
select distinct userpermis0_.user_id as col_0_0_ from markings.user_permissions_map userpermis0_ inner join markings.marking marking1_ on (marking1_.name=userpermis0_.marking_name and marking1_.unique_name=REGEXP_REPLACE(lower(?),'[^a-z0-9]+','-','g')) where (cast(? as varchar(2147483647)) is null or userpermis0_.user_id>?) and (cast(? as varchar(2147483647)) is null or lower(userpermis0_.user_id) like ?) order by userpermis0_.user_id asc limit ? [90150-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:632) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getInvalidPrecisionException(Parser.java:6325) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIfDataType1(Parser.java:6285) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIfDataType(Parser.java:6087) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
```

This is the where Query using JPA:

```
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT u.username"
            + " FROM UserPermissionsMap u"
            + " INNER JOIN Marking m ON m.name = u.markingName AND m.uniqueName = REGEXP_REPLACE(lower(:name), '[^a-z0-9]+', '-', 'g') "
            + " WHERE ( cast(:lastUsernameReturned as text) IS NULL OR u.username > :lastUsernameReturned )"
            + "   AND ( cast(:usernameContains as text) IS NULL OR lower(u.username) LIKE %:usernameContains% )")
```

POM:

```
...
        <h2.version>2.1.214</h2.version>
    </properties>
...
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>${h2.version}</version> << v1.4.200 provided by org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.6
      </dependency>
```

Comment: I have a similar issue: JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Precision ("2147483647") must be between "1" and "1000000000" inclusive

Comment: @ScrappyDev Have you found solution?

Comment: @Vadym - I was able to get it to work without the CAST. See answer below.

Comment: @StefanoBossi I met the identical exception, and it occurred on table of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DOMAINS`. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I'm able to remove the cast all together, but leave the parenthesis and get the same effect for both H2 & PostgreSQL.

`cast(:usernameContains as text)` --> `(:usernameContains)`

They must have fixed the variable replacement when the cast as TEXT was broken.

```
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT u.username"
            + " FROM UserPermissionsMap u"
            + " INNER JOIN Marking m ON m.name = u.markingName AND m.uniqueName = REGEXP_REPLACE(lower(:name), '[^a-z0-9]+', '-', 'g') "
            + " WHERE ( (:lastUsernameReturned) IS NULL OR u.username > :lastUsernameReturned )"
            + "   AND ( (:usernameContains) IS NULL OR lower(u.username) LIKE %:usernameContains% )")
```